# How to change map in StarCraft 2 custom game from 1v1 map

Tags: starcraft-2

I just got Wings of Liberty and I want to play some 4v4's with AIs so I'm not horrible against my friends when we play.

I'm trying to add a game in the custom games and it's just letting me do 1v1 but I can't seem to change the map so I can put in more players.

How do I change the map from Xel'Naga Caverns to something else?

Answer (score 4):

**Step 0:** Make sure you have a *real* copy of Wings of Liberty, and *not* the starter version. From Blizzard's FAQ:

[image: faq]

**Step 1:** From the main menu, pick Custom Games (or hit F3).

[image: main menu]

**Step 2:** Pick "Browse" on the left, then set it to show Blizzard maps in the Melee category.

[image: custom games]

**Step 3:** Scroll down and pick some larger maps.

Comment: Very nice explanation